# Sync data between Android App, Web and Desktop application

Tags: android, server, synchronization, google-cloud-messaging, cloud

Currently, I have an App that sends data to web server.
But, if website sends data to the server, my App does not receive any data from the server.

I want to create an app like Evernote where I don't have to refresh the app to receive data from the server.

So when I sends data from mobile, it has to sync with all other devices.
How do I implement it?? Which method is best for android? 
Is GCM the only way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have tried?

Comment: Check for updates when the app resumes?

Answer (score 1):

We need more information regarding what you have tried implementing for us to provide a better solution since your issue is about code implementation.

You may check [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) as this seems perfect for your situation because with Firebase, "data are synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline". Since you are using Android, you can check this document: [Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Comment: But firebase costs money. Are there any free solution, like uploading to dropbox and syncing?